# Why do I see errors while taking integer input terminated with 0?

Tags: java, for-loop

Write a Java program that will ask you to input numbers and add them until you type a 0. It will then print out

the average of the numbers. Here is a sample of what the output should look like:

```
Please type a sequence of numbers terminated by a 0 

1 

5 

4 

0 

The total was 10.0 

You typed in 3 numbers 

The average is 3.3333
```

I decided to teach myself Java & just started programming not too long ago and I'm still working on fully understanding the combinations of what to use to meet the requirements of a program. I've been doing these online challenges and one asks for a program that inputs numbers and add them until a zero has been inputted by the user, on top of that, it also has to show how many total numbers was typed and the average of those. I already started with a while loop and a scanner but am currently struggling & stuck with the problem:

import java.util.Scanner;
 public class problem4 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type a sequence of numbers terminated by a 0");
    int counter = 0;
    int num = scan.NextInt();
    while (num != 0){
        System.out.println(num);
        if (num == 0) break;
        counter++;
    }
        int total = 0;
        total+=num;
        double average = 0;
        average = total / counter;

            System.out.println("The total was " + total);
            System.out.println("You typed in " + counter + " numbers");
            System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    }
}
```

I get 'cannot find symbol' errors on line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in all with your program: **1.** You forgot to declare `num` before using. Declare it and assign a non zero value to it. **2.** You should be adding `num` to `total` inside the loop so you should also declare it before the loop.

```
int counter = 0, num = 1, total = 0;
while(num != 0){
    num = scan.nextInt();
    if(num == 0)
        break;
    counter++;
    total += num;
}
double average = (double)total/counter;
```

**A suggestion:** Whenever you are dividing an integer with another interger (in this case, total/counter), make sure to cast one to double (or float) to prevent loss of decimal places.

Comment: This answered my question, thank you so much

Comment: **Another suggestion:** Before posting your next question on Stack Overflow, please read this page: [`How do I ask a good question?`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `num` inside the loop. Therefore it is not accessible outside the loop but you are using it outside hence compiler cannot find `num`.
To get the desired result declare `num` before the while loop   
You should study about scope of variables. Your program will not produce the expected output as you should have calculated `total`variable inside while loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `num` variable before using it